# Combine Python + R in data manipulation in Databricks Notebook

Tags: python, r, databricks

Want to combine Py + R

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDataFrame").getOrCreate()

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = [("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 30), ("Charlie", 35), ("Oscar",36), ("Hiromi",41), ("Alejandro", 42)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Age"])
display(df)
```

And R

```
%r
install.packages("sparklyr", version ="1.8.0")
library(sparklyr)
# Connect to the same Spark cluster
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", version = "1.8.0"
               )
```

But I have the error

**Error in spark_connect_gateway(gatewayAddress, gatewayPort, sessionId,  :
Gateway in localhost:8880 did not respond.

Try running `options(sparklyr.log.console = TRUE)` followed by `sc <- spark_connect(...)` for more debugging info.
Some( Error in spark_connect_gateway(gatewayAddress, gatewayPort, sessionId, : Gateway in localhost:8880 did not respond. )**

Any Idea how can I combine both programming Languages in Databricks notebook?